# RapidXml: cannot get children from XML file

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

With the following C++ code, using the RapidXml library, I can only get XML elements at the top level, and not the children:

```
char *text = ... // XML file shown below
using namespace rapidxml;
xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<0>(text);
xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node();
while(node != 0) {
    cout << node->name() << " " << node->value() << endl;
    node = node->next_sibling();    // <-- ???
}
```

XML file:

```
<parent>
   <child>123</child>
</parent>
<parent>
   <child>456</child>
</parent>
```

Actual result:

```
parent
parent
```

Expected result:

```
parent
child 123
parent
child 456
```

How can I get the children?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The second `parent` is a sibling of the first ("siblings" are at the same level - like real-life brothers and sisters).

`node->first_node()` would be the first child of `node`.

The following (uncompiled & untested) code should produce the output you're after:

```
xml_node<> *node = doc.first_node();
while(node != 0) {
    cout << node->name() << endl;
    xml_node<> *child = node->first_node();
    while (child != 0)
    {
        cout << child->name() << " " << child->value() << endl;
        child = child->next_sibling(); 
    }
    node = node->next_sibling();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can save XML data to file, such as "1.xml"

```
<parent>
   <child>123</child>
</parent>
<parent>
   <child>456</child>
</parent>
```

then I think you can do like this：

```
void Parse(std::string strFilePath)
{
    rapidxml::file<> docFile(strFilePath.c_str());
    rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<0>(docFile.data());

    rapidxml::xml_node<> *pNode = doc.first_node();
    for (; pNode != NULL; pNode = pNode->next_sibling())
    {
        std::cout << pNode->name() << std::endl;
        for (rapidxml::xml_node<> *pChildNode = pNode->first_node(); pChildNode != NULL; pChildNode = pChildNode->next_sibling())
        {
            std::cout << " " << pChildNode->name() << " " << pChildNode->value() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```